# Failing to send commands to a TMUX session from PHP

Tags: php, html, linux, bash, tmux

I have a TMUX session running a minecraft server and I am creating a web interface for the server.

Currently I have the following documents:

**command.sh**

```
 #!/bin/bash
 tmux send-keys -t minecraft C-z "$@" Enter
```

**index.php**

```
<?PHP
    if($_POST) {
        $commandString = $_POST['inputCommand'];
        $output = shell_exec('./command.sh $commandString');
        echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
        }
?>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="inputCommand" placeholder="Type Command"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Execute" />
    </form>
```

command.sh works in a terminal in that I can use all standard commands in the manner

```
 ./command.sh "/help"
```

However I cannot execute this script from php using the above methodology. I have added both www-data and www-user to sudoers and attempted to

`shell_exec('sudo ./command.sh $commandString')`

But that has not worked either.

When the submit button is clicked, output is echoed but it is blank.

Can someone please help in pointing out where my methodology for executing the script has gone wrong?

---

**EDIT**
I have taken two screenshots, one before and one after to further clarify.

[image]

Comment: What is going wrong? Are you getting an error? What are you getting as output? What commands are you trying that fail? Do you realize this is a *gaping* security hole?

Comment: No error, output is empty, the commands are above. This literally returns nothing and the command is not executed. Thats why im so puzzled and posted here
Yes I understand the security implications, this is behind a 2 separate login screens.

Comment: @EtanReisner please see above, I have posted a screenshot to clarify

Comment: Login screens don't matter. This is still a gaping hole and doesn't need to be as huge of a hole as it is. Unless you really need to allow arbitrary input you should definitely be stripping out all sorts of things (shell metacharacters, quotes, non-printable characters, etc.) from the input before passing it to the shell.

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Comment: Trying using the double quotes in your `shell_exec` line as well

Comment: Aside: the high levels of up/downvotes may be because of [the Meta effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275763/472495).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`command.sh` is having a problem and outputting something to stderr. `shell_exec` only returns to you stdout, so you're not seeing the error.  Try appending "2>&1" to the end of your command, like

```
$output = shell_exec('./command.sh $commandString 2>&1');
```

This will send stderr to stdout and let you see what's happening.  Remove the "2>&1" once you've debugged the problem.  As pointed out in the comments, I imagine the actual issue is that you are using single quotes, which mean $commandString is being interpreted literally.  Try double quotes instead!

**Warning!!!**  This is really insecure.   You're passing an unsanitized parameter obtained from POST to a command running as a user that's in sudoers.  Regardless of two login screens, you should sanitize your input.

Comment: Actually, *as written*, this is perfectly safe - there's no variable substitution going on. The command being executed is a constant string. And that may be why the behavior isn't as expected. "Fixing" it, of course, will introduce the cautioned vulnerability.

Comment: I used your above suggestion of redirecting standard error to standard out, I found out that TMUX could not find the string, I changed it to su -c command and it worked.

I also found a better way about 10 minutes after this worked in that minecraft has a built in Rcon function and I used that to communicate through php post forms. Thus, no shell_exec and all a lot safer.

Comment: @MichaelBetterton Awesome I'm glad I could help and hopefully your future experiences on SO don't involve multiple meta threads debating what's OK  :)